# Mailinglist for OSS?

Tags: open-source, mailing-list

I'm running an open source project and I'm wanting to externalize development discussions that we have been having by email, make them public and allow anyone to take part in the conversation. For this, I've been thinking about setting up a mailing list.

Given this, is a mailing list currently the be "device" for this. If so what do people think is the best tool to use for this? Is Google Groups still the best tool for mailing lists, is there something people that OSS is gravitating more towards? Surely there is something better, Google Groups seems outdated.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Mailman](http://www.list.org/) is a very popular package used on mailing list servers; you may want to use this to manage and process your list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Librelist? A number of open source projects is using it such as Flask. [Librelist.com](http://librelist.com/)